# Set Xcode flags in order to embed python in my C++ project

Tags: python, c++, xcode, cflags, ldflags

I'm trying to embed python in my C++ project. I need to do it in order to use some functions that implement the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test that are not available in C++.

For now I'm just trying to see if Xcode is able to link and compile a simple program that embeds Python.
The code I'm trying to compile is the following:

```
#include<Python/Python.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* variable;
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can understand from the instructions I've read here: [1. Embedding Python in Another Application - 1.6 Compiling and Linking under Unix-like systems](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems) and here: [Python/C API Reference Manual - Introduction](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/intro.html) in order for this to compile I have to add some additional flags to the compiler and the linker.

In order to find out which flags should I add, I've run the following two commands in my terminal (of which I include the corresponding output):

```
$ python3.6-config --cflags          
-I/Users/user/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -I/Users/user/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/user/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/user/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64

$ python3.6-config --ldflags
-lpython3.6m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -Wl,-stack_size,1000000 -framework CoreFoundation
```

Where I replaced the actual name of my user folder with `user`.

Now, in order to add these flags to the Xcode compiler and linker I went to my project settings window and under `Build Settings -> Other C Flags` and `Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags` I added the flags that I've reported above.

But when I compile I get this error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And it doesn't go away even if I comment all the lines in the `main` function except for `return 0`.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using `Xcode 8.3.2` and my Python distribution is: `Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found a solution. Not sure if it's actually the right one (since I'm not an expert and I don't really understand the reason why now it works), but I'm going to post it anyway.

The thing is that if you look at the instructions in this page: [1. Embedding Python in Another Application - 1.6. Compiling and Linking under Unix-like systems](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems) you can see that when executing the command `python3.6-config --ldflags` the output contains a flag `-L/opt/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m` while in my case it doesn't.

So after figuring out that the flag that gave me the linking error was `-lpython3.6m`, I thought that maybe it was due to the fact that the linker couldn't find the directory in which my python distribution was or something like that.

So I looked in my hard drive for a path to a folder with a name similar to the one shown on the webpage and I found that `/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin` was a path to a folder with a name very similar to the one I was looking for, except for the "-darwin" at the end of the folder's name that's probably there because I'm on a macOS distribution (maybe that's why the command `python3.6-config --ldflags` didn't find it? I don't know).

After this I just added `-L/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin` at the beginning of Xcode's "Other Liker Flags" and everything (almost) compiled just fine.

I say "almost" because I also had to rename the `include` at the beginning of my code from `#include<Python/Python.h>` to `#include<Python.h>` (maybe because by using the first one I'm including the system default Python distribution while with the second I'm including the Anaconda one? Again, I don't know).

Anyway now everything compiles just fine and so I thought to share how I did it in case somebody else is in the same situation.